# visualforce apex tag JS error when selecting picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, tag

Anyone have already encounter this issue? Error will occur if you select the any of the picklist. Any other way to fix the issue?

**VisualForce  Page**

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Task">

     <apex:form>

     <apex:inputField value="{!Task.WhoId}" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!Task.WhatId}" />

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**JS ERROR**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[secid=j_id0:j_id2:j_id3_mlbtn]' is not a valid selector.

**EDIT : Adding Screenshot for reference**

[image]

Comment: when do you get this error ? when saving the VF page or when running it ? I tried the exact same code in my dev org and it works fine.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna running in VF page. open your google chrome developer console and you will see the JS error.

Comment: This error may be coming from a browser extension. Turn off all your browser extensions (via Window -> Extensions in Chrome) and see if the error stops.

Comment: @KeithC I already did but the error still the same.

Comment: In the Sources tab, hit the Pause on Exceptions button so we can see what line is causing it. You could have features on that others dont so it would really help to know whos doing that line.